# Update a row +1 in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to update a row in the database but haven't found a way to do this in the CakePHP way `(unless I query the row to retrieve and update)`.

```
UPDATE mytable (field) VALUES (field+1) WHERE id = 1
```

In CodeIgniter, it would have been as simple as:

```
$this->db->set('field', 'field+1', FALSE);
$this->db->where('id', 1);
$this->db->update('mytable');
```

How do I do this without querying the row first, retrieve the value, then updating the row with the information I got?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't think CakePHP has a similar method for doing this in a normal save() on a single row.

But the updateAll() method, which updates multiple rows, does support SQL snippets like so:

```
$this->Widget->updateAll(
    array('Widget.numberfield' => 'Widget.numberfield + 1'),
    array('Widget.id' => 1)
);
```

The first param is an array of fields/values to be updated, and the second param are the conditions for which rows to update.

Apart from that I think the only thing is to use:

```
$this->Widget->query('YOUR SQL QUERY HERE');
```

Which lets you query with raw SQL. [EDIT: but this is *not* recommended as it bypasses the ORM.]

Comment: you were doing ok until you started recommending query()

Comment: @dogmatic69 - You're right I should have mentioned that query() is not at all recommended. I never use it myself for CRUD-like operations, and the only time I can think it's useful is working with table metadata or something really unusual.

Comment: If you go this route you can not expect behavior callbacks to fire (at least to the best of my knowledge)

Comment: Yes very good point - using updateAll definitely bypasses model and behavior callbacks. To ensure callbacks are fired it would have to be done more like Abba's answer, but that involves one extra initial read from the DB.

Comment: What if this "1" was a variable? For example $time... I try to add and it doesn't work even that a put inside or outtside the ' '.

Comment: 'Widget.numberfield' => 'Widget.numberfield + $time' or 'Widget.numberfield' => 'Widget.numberfield' + $time  both are not working.

Comment: For PHP Cake 3 ORM, what worked for me was array('Widget.numberfield = Widget.numberfield + 1')

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
    class WidgetsController extends AppController {
        public function someFunction( $id = null ){
            if( $id ){

                // read all fields from the model
                // alternately you can $this->Widget->read( array( 'field' ), $id );
                $this->Widget->read( null, $id );

                // grab the 'field' field so we don't have to type out the data array
                $field = $this->Widget->data[ 'Widget' ][ 'field' ];

                // where field is the name of the field to be incremented
                $this->Widget->set( 'field', $field + 1 );
                $this->Widget->save( );
            }

            // someday cake devs will learn to spell referrer
            $this->redirect( $this->referer( ));
        }
    }
?>
```

Basically you are passing the id, if it exists you [read the Widget model](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1029/read) (see the notes above, null as 1st param read the entire table) and then you are using [Model::set](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1031/Saving-Your-Data) to st the field to a value one greater than itself - remember to cast to int if you store the field as a char/varchar - and then save the model.

Comment: OP mentioned they didn't want to query the row before updating, which is what read() does. Also Widget->field() is a method, not a property, so you need parentheses and you need to pass the field name in as a parameter too.

Comment: read the code again - I used Model::set not Model::field - and I used it as specified in the docs and api.  -- in this case I use Model::set to set the 'field' column to a value. Confusing choice of a field name to provide but your comment implies you didn't read very carefully. I missed the no querying before updating requirement so I guess we're even.

Comment: Hi Abba - OK I see the confusion over the example field name 'field' vs the method field(), I did indeed assume you meant the 'field' method. But I've always thought that Model::read() pulls the values into Model::$data, and never into individual Model attributes like ActiveRecord does. So you'd have to access the current value at $this->Widget->data['Widget']['field'] - but not $this->Widget->field. Please correct me if I'm wrong as this has always seemed like a limitation with cake to me.

Comment: Model::set( key, value ) sets the Model->data[ Model->alias ][ key ]  -- the example is taken almost directly from the docs link in my post. If you want to, run a quick test and reply back if it doesn't work as I described.

Comment: Your use of Model::set() is fine, but the code "$this->Widget->field" will trigger an error "Undefined property: Widget::$field" as there will be no property called "field" on the model. You should change that line to $this->Widget->set( 'field', $this->Widget->data['Widget']['field'] + 1 );

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect this. Thanks.