# Update a row by 1 in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-model, cakephp-3.0

I have searched for this question and found many similar answers like this one

[Update a row +1 in CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796219/update-a-row-1-in-cakephp)

and this is what the accepted answer looks like

> $this->Widget->updateAll(
>
> ```
>       array('Widget.numberfield' => 'Widget.numberfield + 1'),
>
>       array('Widget.id' => 1)
> ```
>
> );

Now iam using this query in cakephp3.
Here is what mine looks like

> $Questions=$this->loadModel('Questions');
>
> $Questions->updateAll(
>
> ```
>        array('questions.trend' => 'questions.trend + 1'),
>
>        array('questions.description' => $undashed_title)
> ```
>
> );

Every thing is working fine and query's are executing but when i check debugger for sql log, Here's what i found

> UPDATE questions SET questions.trend = 'questions.trend + 1' WHERE questions.description = 'What type'

But my value in database is not updating like it should be
(Iam saying this beacuse i also have copied this query on phpmyadmin console and its not working )

I believe the query should look like this

> UPDATE questions SET questions.trend = questions.trend+1 WHERE questions.description = 'What Type'

Any help would be appreciated ,Thanks :)

Comment: I corrected version from 2.x to 3.x as you otherwise confuse people since you are *actually* using 3.0!

Comment: Maybe, you should look at http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#raw-expressions

Comment: "its not working" - is a pretty useless description of a problem... And the error message is...?

Comment: @UltimateProgrammer_BR :looking at it,thanks
but then again real question is if it is working for others why not for me?

Comment: It's not working™ because CakePHP 3 seems like diverge queries and values, `questions.trend + 1` is a query and you are passing it like a value, so, it become a value in the end. You need to say to ORM that it's a query and not a value.

Comment: @burzum: i have tried to explain every bit of my question (at least i think so) if you look it clearly.and there is no error message but the ORM query builder has build a query which is not working.

Comment: @UltimateProgrammer_BR: i think i understood your explanation to the problem but again how to tell ORM?? Sorry i am very new to Cake !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as i said on comments, CakePHP 3 diverge a `value` from a `expression`, and the increment thing that you trying to do is a `expression`, to solve your "problem" you shall dig deep on CakePHP docs, and so you will find this **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#bulk-updates**, yeah, right what you want. So, it becomes:

```
// load your beloved model
$questions = $this->loadModel('Questions');
// create a beauty expression
$expression = new QueryExpression('questions.trend + 1');
// execute a update with the beauty expression
$questions->updateAll(
   array('questions.trend' => $expression),
   array('questions.description' => $undashed_title)
);
```

And don't forget to load `QueryExpression`'s namespace with `use Cake\Database\Expression\QueryExpression;`.

> Yes, this is the wrong way to do on CakePHP 3, you shall the CakePHP's ORM, and move the increment thing to the model layer.